# Channel Images with Animated GIFs

Tags: channel-images

I am looking for a way to store animated GIFs using Channel Images.  I'm OK with the re-sized options not working.  I figured I would just link to the original image.  Unfortunately, the original image is not so original because it gets converted to JPG.

Is there any way to configure Channel Images to store the original file type?